# A Gauss sum over a field.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, field-theory, gauss-sums

Let $K$ be a field (not necessarily $\mathbb C$) and let $\zeta=\zeta_n$ be a primitive $n$th root of unity in $\bar K$.

I would like to know if there is a formula calculating
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n \zeta^{-k^2}.$$

If it exists please tell me the formula.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Experiments suggest that if $n\equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ then the sum is $\pm\sqrt{n}$ and if $n\equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ then the sum is $\pm\sqrt{n}i.$

Comment: Related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90541/determining-the-value-of-a-gauss-sum?rq=1

Comment: I would like to consider this for a general filed $K$ not necessarily $mathbb C$. Is the same computation true?

Comment: Since it is in fact true over $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$, the computation should transfert to quite a lot of cases, including finite fields or $p$-adic.